# Angular Material Design: build template with top navbar and left sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi i want build a simple template using Angular Material 2:

[image]

this is the code

```
<md-toolbar>
    <button><md-icon>menu</md-icon></button>￼
    <h1>Angular</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container>

  <md-sidenav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/Foo" routerLinkActive="active">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/Bar" routerLinkActive="active">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/Baz" routerLinkActive="active">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </md-sidenav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <footer></footer>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

i have a bit of problem:

1. the sidenav cover the router-outlet
2. the router-outlet isn't 100% height

it's possible achieve this template only using material components (without css hack)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a close sample of your template. I just added color to easily distinguish them.

```
<md-toolbar color="accent">
    <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>￼
    <h1>Angular</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container style="height: 91vh;background: yellow">
  
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" style="background: orange">
    Sidenav!
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
 </md-tab-group>

</md-sidenav-container>

<footer style="background: skyblue">This is footer</footer>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/EBSjqUIUka9koOCYoaU6?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: what if we have separate components for toolbar, sidebar, main content and footer, I tried putting `</md-sidenav-container>` in footer component but getting error